# Online Help implementation in java Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to implement Online Help in my Java Web Project. For Example User is in Page 1 he clicks help button then help page should get opened related to Page 1. if he is in page 2 then help related to page 2 should be displayed along with the TOC next,prev and search option. After googling i found out Eclipse help system http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp and http://javahelp.java.net/ can be used. Eclipse help system looks more professional.

i . Is there any other tools ?

ii. Also How to make Eclipse help system go online so that user can use it from any where after hitting the url.

iii. Using Eclipse help system will it be possible to open pages 1 page 2 as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some R&D i found out Eclipse help system is best for documenting Help. It has all the features required.Searching, Print, Tree View,Customising etc.. etc...All information can be found at http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_help.htm and http://dita.xml.org/wiki/an-infocenter-product-plugin-cookbook this link is nice for statup